# Configure all ports located on other switches from one switch

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, etherchannel

**Introduction**

If VLANs are configured on one switch (Switch1) and this switch is subsequently connected to another switch (Switch2) using a port channel, the VLANs configured on Switch1 are visible as well if the console cable is plugged to Switch2. However, the ports assigned to VLANs by Switch1 are not visible, while viewing the configuration of Switch2.

**Question**

Is it possible to view the configuration of the ports of all switches in the network by plugging the console cable to one switch like this is the case for VLANs?

Comment: What model of switch are you using?

Comment: cisco 3560 Layer 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it isn't. The reason why you can see VLANs on both switches is VTP [(VLAN Trunk Protocol)](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/vtp/10558-21.html)

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to view the configuration of the ports of all switches in the network by plugging the console cable to one switch

As they are independent, free-standing switches, *No*. If they were in a stack or cluster, then the answer most likely would be yes -- they'd all appear as one switch.

Comment: Cisco 3560 can't be stacked.

Comment: *or cluster* -- 'tho the 3560's clustering is a joke.

Comment: The Cisco cluster mechanism doesn't really address the "configure all ports from one switch" as you need to connect to each switch individually (through the master).  It just allows for the use of a single IP address for management.

Comment: CNA is also a webapp. (see also: "joke")